# How to format text data with Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I just began using Azure SQL Query Editor to help me learn.

I have problems formatting TEXT data when inserting data. I know I should be formatting data with `"Quotations"` around TEXT data, however, I continue to run into the following error: Incorrect syntax near `'“'`.

Example of table and dummy data:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE ( eno INTEGER(11),  ename TEXT(30),  zip INTEGER(5) DEFAULT 47405,  hdate DATE, dept TEXT (30),  salary INTEGER(15,3), constraint EMPLOYEE_PK primary key (eno));

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (5476343153, “Stanley Keller”, , 06-Mar-99, “Sales”, 75689);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (5286469147, “Sergio Murray”, , 13-Mar-92, “Marketing”, 148769);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2454152346, “Laurie Hawkins”, , 22-Mar-98, “Marketing”, 92474);
```

Why is this happening to me? Thank you.

Comment: Single quotes are the SQL standard for delimiting strings, not double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Gordon is correct - single identifiers are the norm for ANSI SQL.

In SQL Server/SQL Azure, if you want to use a different quoted identifier, there is a session option to allow it if needed.

Here is the documentation on that feature which should make your original query work (non-standard SQL):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following. It worked for me.

```
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE
GO
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE ( eno BigInt, ename NVARCHAR(30), zip INT DEFAULT 47405, hdate DATE, dept NVARCHAR(30), salary decimal(15,3), constraint EMPLOYEE_PK primary key (eno));
GO
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (eno, ename, hdate, dept, salary) VALUES (5476343153, 'Stanley Keller', '06-Mar-99', 'Sales', 75689);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (eno, ename, hdate, dept, salary) VALUES (5286469147, 'Sergio Murray',  '13-Mar-92', 'Marketing', 148769); 
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (eno, ename, hdate, dept, salary) VALUES (2454152346, 'Laurie Hawkins', '22-Mar-98', 'Marketing', 92474);
```

Please take note the data types were wrong, You were treating integer like decimal and for integers the data type is int. Also you don't have to specify commas for the fields where you want the default value to take place. On the eno field I had to specify BigInt as data type since the values on the INSERT statements are to big for the integer (int) data type.

I changed double quotes for single quotes on those INSERT statements.